How to extract numbers from an image of a table/grid of numbers?
Not from a calc or excel cell's, but a screenshot of them. Must be OCR. I've been recommended to use microsoft Power Query or microsoft Powertoys, but I dont know how to install them on ubuntu, I do have microsoft office 2013 though. I've also tried many free OCR programs from my software repository.
Here's an example of what I need to convert:

And I need to convert it to this below, I need to extract the numbers and separate each cell with a comma:
2 ,3, 5, 12, 2, 1, 8, 9, 42, 45, 1, 23, 32, 4, 12, 3

-Thanks

Does Insert data from picture - Microsoft Support answer your question?

@DavidPostill, thanks,but I know about that already, the problem is getting microsoft 365 on my ubuntu, which I dont have, and that feature isnt on 2013 Excel, and I dont have the money to pay for 365 either. And I cant run a virtual Window OS because my laptop is only 6GB RAM.
